# What to do if you don't know if you have DOT 3 or DOT in your brake lines?

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid

The brake fluid on my 98 Mada 626 is black and nasty looking, and I'm planning on bleeding the brakes to change it.  However, I don't know what's currently in it because the Workshop Service Manual says, ***"SAE J1703, FMVSS 116 DOT-3 or DOT 4"***

Since I'm going to bleed all the brakes, can I just use which ever one I want and disregard whatever might already be in there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dot 3 and Dot 4 are mixable, you can use whatever you want.

Just do not put Dot 5 into it, thats a whole different thing and not mixable with Dot 3 or Dot 4.

Comment: And do not confuse DOT5.1 with DOT5, because DOT5.1 ***IS*** compatible. Also, if you do mix DOT3 in with DOT4, consider your system to be working at a DOT3 level as far as performance goes.